# Mysql unknown column in select sub query

Tags: mysql

It throw Unknown column `company_names` in 'where clause' on

```
SELECT `user`.`id`, 
    `user`.`email`,  
    (SELECT  Group_concat(c.name)  
       FROM user_company uc  
          inner join company as c  
            on uc.company_id = c.id  
      where uc.user_id = user.id  
      GROUP BY uc.user_id) as company_names  
 FROM `user` AS `user`  
WHERE  company_names LIKE '%sa%' LIMIT 0, 20;
```

Comment: Instead of the sub select, why not just use LEFT JOIN, GROUP BY and GROUP_CONCAT?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use alias for column name in where

but you could use an inner join on the subquery and filter on this

```
  SELECT `user`.`id`, 
      `user`.`email`,  
      t.my_company_name

  FROM `user` AS `user`  
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT user_id,  Group_concat(c.name)   my_company_name
    FROM user_company uc  
    inner join company as c  on uc.company_id = c.id  
         AND uc.user_id = user.id  
    GROUP BY uc.user_id
  )  t on t.user_id = user.id and t.my_company_names LIKE '%sa%' 
  LIMIT 0, 20;
```